# What does insubstantial mean?

Tags: dnd-4e

We've seen a few powers that make a creature insubstantial now, but we haven't been able to find out what it means.  What does it mean and where can we get a clear definition?

Comment: On the off-chance that you were looking for a real-world rather than D&D definition, "insubstantial" means "lacking substance", i.e. without material presence, ethereal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rules for Insubstantial can be found on page 277 of the 4th Edition Player's Handbook.

The short version is that insubstantial creatures take half damage.

Comment: +1: The long version precises that it takes half damage from ongoing damage too. :)

Answer (score -2):

In 2nd edition you became 'insubstantial' because of a spell like ectoplasmic form, which turned you incorporeal or 'not real' in a way. So the effect in 4e (like Ectoplasmic Armor for example), similiar, in that you take half damage. In earlier editions you couldn't be hurt except by +1 or magical weapons, or by spells, when incorporeal.

Comment: The question is about 4e. While interesting, the info about previous editions is not related to how it works in the given context and should be removed.