# Insubstantial when swimming does what exactly?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

If I am swimming in the water, without any swim speed or special swimming ability, and then I become insubstantial, what will happen?

Can I move more easily? Can I ascend or descend arbitrarily?

Would I use my normal (land) speed, or my modified swim speed (presumably half my current speed)?

Comment: [Related] [What does insubstantial mean?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9603)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The same thing that would happen if you weren't insubstantial.**

From the RC, p226:

> While a creature is insubstantial, it takes half damage from any attack that deals damage to it. Ongoing damage is also halved.

Nothing in there about it being easier or harder to swim. Insubstantial halves damage from most sources, and that's about it. You'll notice it also doesn't make you fly or fall through the ground to the center of the earth when you're on land.

Comment: Yup; It might be more complicated if the character also had phasing, but even so, 4E is a pretty straightforward game.